# What number I am?

Tags: mathematics

- I am a 4 digit number
- The digit in the ones place is 6
- The value of the digit in the hundreds places is 500
- The digits in the tens and thousands places are the same and they add up to 8

What number I am?

Comment: To the down-voters : This question has already been **put on hold**. So there's no sense in serial downvoting. Please leave it as such.

Comment: Hello everyone, I am sorry. I am a new contributor in this community. I'll try to be better next time. Thank you.

Comment: Why was this closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a 4 digit number

> xxxx

The digit in the ones place is 6

> xxx6

The value of the digit in the hundreds places is 500

> x5x6

The digits in the tens and thousands places are the same and they add up to 8

> 4546

Maybe some traps in the question...?